# Convert Formula into Values

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I want to convert a VLOOKUP formula passed through this code into values for the same range:

```
Dim DWR, MHR, P, D, A As Worksheet

Set A = Sheets("ALLOC")
Set DWR = Sheets("DWREP")
Set MHR = Sheets("MACH-HRS")
Set P = Sheets("PRODUCTION")
Set D = Sheets("DELAYS")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim last_row, last_row1, last_row2 As Long
last_row = MHR.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last_row1 = P.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last_row2 = D.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
last_row3 = A.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False

A.Range("AI2").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)"
A.Range("AJ2").Formula = "=D2"
A.Range("AI2:AJ2").AutoFill Destination:=A.Range("AI2:AJ" & last_row3)


P.Range("AI2").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(A2,B2)"
P.Range("AJ2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(AI2,ALLOC!$AI:$AJ,2,0)"
P.Range("AI2:AJ2").AutoFill Destination:=P.Range("AI2:AJ" & last_row1)
For i = 2 To last_row1
    varr = P.Cells(i, 36).Value
    P.Cells(i, 36).Value = varr
Next i
```

However, I get #N/A Values when I have tried iteration through the range with `.Value = .Value`. Also, I have tried using for the specifix region, but it returns the same result.

```
 P.Activate
 P.Range("AJ2:AJ" & last_row1).Select
 Selection.Copy
 Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
 ActiveSheet.Select
 Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

When I tried to do the same thing manually, there is no problem. 
This is quite mind-boggling. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use `Worksheets.Select` you can't perform the same operation on all sheet at once. On each sheet use `P.Range("AI2:AJ2").Copy P.Range("AI2:AJ2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`.

Comment: This is just example which I have adapted, however, it still yields the same results. The problem should be something else.

Comment: Before the paste are all the values correct?

Comment: Yes! I have tried that multiple time. And if everything described is done manually, there is no problem, which is the strangest thing.

Comment: The code provided would not cause the problem you are describing. Show all the code.

Comment: Ok. I will edit the post. DONE

Comment: In both cases shown, the result is the same.

Comment: When stepping through your code, what is `varr` after `varr = P.Cells(i, 36).Value` for the first iteration?

Comment: Just in case, I tried with an intermediate variable, if directly taking the value was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case resulted to be the following. When this setting is like that `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` Excel cannot actually compute the formula. So making it `xlCalculationAutomatic` before running this particular lines of code solves the problem.